# Google Sheets call sheet by name based on cell value of current tab

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to hide or unhide specific tabs by creating functions.  The problem is the sheet name will change depending on who's using it.  Is it possible to get a sheet name based on the value of a cell on the current tab?

Example:

```
function HideIncOne() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('G18').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('INCENTIVE #1'), true);
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().hideSheet();
};
```

I tried .getSheetByRange but obviously that didn't work.  So I'm trying to call the text from cell B4 of the current tab and make google sheets hide a sheet with the same name as the text in cell B4.

Comment: I believe you could use developer metadata to keep track of the sheet even if it's name changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Get the active sheet's `B4` value
- Get Sheet with that name using `getSheetByName` and hide it

```
function HideSheetInB4() {
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet
    .getSheetByName(
      spreadsheet
        .getActiveSheet()
        .getRange('B4')
        .getValue()
    )
    .hideSheet();
}
```

Comment: I get this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'hideSheet' of null

Comment: @LonestarDads It means you don't have a valid sheet name in the active tab's B4 cell.

Comment: Haha I'm an idiot, thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to call the sheet name like above in this script for "Sheet2": 
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("CONTROL PANEL");
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");

  var cell1 = sheet1.getRange('B2');

  if (cell1.getValue() == 2) {
    sheet2.hideSheet();
  }

  if (cell1.getValue() == 3) {
    sheet2.showSheet();
  }
}

Comment: @LonestarDads Sure. But you won't get the active sheet or the active cell.

Answer (score 0):

#### Here's a simple way to put developer metadata into selected sheets

In this case I only wanted to mess with my sheets that are named with the string "Sheet" followed by 1 or more digits.

Hence the regex `/Sheet\d{1,}/` or `/Sheet\d+/`

```
function addingmetadatatosomesheet() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.getSheets().forEach((sh, i) => {
    if (sh.getName().match(/^Sheet\d{1,}/)) {
      sh.addDeveloperMetadata('shidx', i + 1);
    }
  });
}
```

#### This is how I read the meta data.

```
function findSheetMetaData() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.getSheets().forEach(sh => {
    let v = sh.createDeveloperMetadataFinder().withKey('shidx').find();
    if (v && v.length > 0) {
      v.forEach(e => {
        Logger.log(`SheetName: ${sh.getName()} Metadata: ${e.getValue()}`);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

#### Execution Log Output:

```
1:37:31 PM  Info    SheetName: Sheet01 Metadata: 7.0
1:37:31 PM  Info    SheetName: Sheet1 Metadata: 8.0
1:37:31 PM  Info    SheetName: Sheet2 Metadata: 9.0
1:37:32 PM  Info    SheetName: Sheet3 Metadata: 10.0
1:37:32 PM  Info    SheetName: Sheet4 Metadata: 11.0
1:37:32 PM  Info    SheetName: Sheet5 Metadata: 12.0
```

- And this represent a solution that your casual user is not going to find easy to mess with.

Comment: Sorry this is a bit too confusing for me.  I'm looking for a script to put in that I can easily edit.  I need the script to call cell B4 of the active sheet, find the sheet with the same name as listed in B4 and hide that sheet.

Comment: That's okay but if you can change it easily so can other users making it a lot less reliable.